# Largest/smallest dimensions possible?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $T : \mathbb R^5 \to \mathbb R^2$ is a linear transformation, what is the smallest dimension that $\ker(T)$ can have? If $L : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^4$ is a linear transformation, what is the largest dimension that $\operatorname{Range}(L)$ can have? What is the smallest dimension that $\ker(LT)$ can have, where $LT : \mathbb R^5 \to \mathbb R^4$ is the composition of $L$ and $T$, $LT(v) = L(T(v))$? What is the largest dimension that $\operatorname{Range}(LT)$ can have?

I assume I am using the theorem that $\dim(\operatorname{Range}(T)) + \dim(\ker(T)) = \dim(V)$, right? (Assuming Let $T:V→W$)

How do I go about solving for the missing variables?

Comment: If the sum of two numbers is constant, i.e. $x + y = c$ and you want the largest $x$, what must be true of $y$? What if you want the smallest $x$?

Comment: How do you go about it? Just use the formula. So $\dim(V)=5$ in the first case. So $5=k+i$.

Comment: Are there any limits on what either can be? So can the dim(ker(T)) be zero?

Comment: @user92399 Think about it. If the kernel has dimension zero, what is the dimension of the range? Does it make any sense at all?

Comment: "I assume I am using the theorem that $\dim(\operatorname{Range}(T)) + \dim(\ker(T)) = \dim(V)$, right?" That's one of the stranger sentences I've seen on MSE in a while.

Comment: @user92399 What is the kernel of the map $x \mapsto x$ (say, from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$?  How about $x \mapsto 0$ (from, say $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$?  What does this tell you about what the dimension of the kernel could be?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

As a first step notice that, for a linear transformation $L:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, the largest dimension for the range is $m$.  This, with the mentioned [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), solve immediately your first question.

And, with a bit more of reasoning, also the other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Every linear transformation is equivalent to some matrix. For the first case the matrix is $M_{5\times 2}$ whose rank is at most $2$ and according to rank-nullity theorem **the kernel space dimension is at least $3$**. For the 2nd case similarly **the range space dimension is at most $2$**. You can easily solve the other cases.